# RecyclerView Only Shows One Item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two items, and I wanna display both of them. But the problem is, I can show only one item in RecyclerView.

I've already tried to create two ViewHolder in one adapter, but still only can display one item.

**ShowFavouriteList.java**

```
public class ShowFavouriteList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private TextView noFavtsTV;
    AppPreferences appPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_favourite_list);

        SwipeRefreshLayout pullToRefresh = findViewById(R.id.pullToRefresh);
        pullToRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });

        //toolbar logo and desc
        Toolbar topToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarTidur);
        setSupportActionBar(topToolBar); //munculkan menu ke toolbar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //this line shows back button

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        noFavtsTV = findViewById(R.id.no_favt_text);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
        SharedPreferences sPTuru = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyTuru", 0);
        PreferenceMenejer preferenceMenejer = new PreferenceMenejer(sharedPreferences, sPTuru);
        appPreferences = new AppPreferences(preferenceMenejer);

        fetchData();

    } // Oncreate

    private void fetchData() {
        List<Story> storyList = appPreferences.getFavouriteCardList();
        List<YukulModel> yukulList = appPreferences.getFavouriteYukul();

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new AdapterFavList1(this, storyList, yukulList, appPreferences));

        if(storyList != null && storyList.size() > 0) {
            showNoFavtText(false);

            for(int i=0; i<storyList.size(); i++) {
                Story story = new Story();
                story.getName();
                storyList.add(story);
            }
        }

        if(yukulList != null && yukulList.size() > 0) {
            showNoFavtText(false);

            for(int i=0; i<yukulList.size(); i++) {
                YukulModel stori = new YukulModel();
                stori.getName();
                yukulList.add(stori);
            }
        }

    }

    private void showNoFavtText(boolean show) {
        noFavtsTV.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE); //jika data yang ditampilkan tidak ada, maka show noFavsTv
        recyclerView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); //jika data yang ditampilkan tidak ada, maka don't show rV
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    // Agar back button pada halaman induk settings berfungsi
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                this.finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**AdapterFavList1.java**

```
public class AdapterFavList1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public static final String ACTION_LIKE_IMAGE_CLICKEDD = "action_like_image_button";
    final int VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR = 0;
    final int VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL = 1;

    private Context context;
    private List<Story> storyList;
    private List<YukulModel> yukulList;

    private int changedItemPosition;
    private boolean isLiked;
    private AppPreferences appPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    public AdapterFavList1(Context context, List<Story> storyList, List<YukulModel> yukulList, AppPreferences appPreferences) {
        this.context = context;
        this.storyList = storyList;
        this.yukulList = yukulList;
        this.appPreferences = appPreferences;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR) {
            return new tidurViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_story_favourite_list, parent, false));
        }
        if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL) {
            return new yukulViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_favourite_yukul, parent, false));
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(holder instanceof tidurViewHolder){
            ((tidurViewHolder) holder).setViewData(storyList.get(position), holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }

        if(holder instanceof yukulViewHolder){
            ((yukulViewHolder) holder).viewDataYukul(yukulList.get(position), holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(storyList== null) {
            return yukulList.size();
        }
        else if(storyList != null) {
            return storyList.size();
        }

        if(yukulList==null) {
            return storyList.size();
        }
        else {
            return yukulList.size();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        if(storyList != null && storyList.size() > 0){
            return VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR;
        }

        if(yukulList != null && yukulList.size() > 0){
            return VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL;
        }

        return -1;
    }


    public void tidurPutHeart(boolean isChecked, int position) {
        SharedPreferences tidursharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Turu", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor tidureditor = tidursharedPreferences.edit();
        Story tidurstory = storyList.get(position);
        tidureditor.putBoolean(tidurstory.getIdStory(), isChecked);
        tidureditor.commit();
    }

    public boolean tidurGetHeart(int position) {
        SharedPreferences tidursharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Turu", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Story tidurstory = storyList.get(position);
        boolean isChecked = tidursharedPreferences.getBoolean(tidurstory.getIdStory(), false);
        return isChecked;
    }

    public void yukulPutHeart(boolean isChecked, int position) {
        SharedPreferences yukulsharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Yukul", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor yukuleditor = yukulsharedPreferences.edit();
        YukulModel yukulstory = yukulList.get(position);
        yukuleditor.putBoolean(yukulstory.getIdStory(), isChecked);
        yukuleditor.commit();
    }

    public boolean yukulGetHeart(int position) {
        SharedPreferences yukulsharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Yukul", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        YukulModel yukulstory = yukulList.get(position);
        boolean isChecked = yukulsharedPreferences.getBoolean(yukulstory.getIdStory(), false);
        return isChecked;
    }


    //ViewHolder
        public class tidurViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private CheckBox likeCheckBox;

        public tidurViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            likeCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button_cb);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // send selected contact in callback
                    Story story = storyList.get(getLayoutPosition());
                    int ambilId = Integer.parseInt(story.getIdStory());

                    if (0 == ambilId) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaMauTidur.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else if (1 == ambilId) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaBangunt.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else if (2 == ambilId) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaJimak.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No destination page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        } // itemView


        public void setViewData(final Story story, final int adapterPosition) {

            textView.setText(story.getName());

            if (story.getIsLiked() == 1) {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            }
            else {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            }

            boolean isChecked = tidurGetHeart(getAdapterPosition()); // The problem lays here
            likeCheckBox.setChecked(isChecked);

            likeCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    changedItemPosition = adapterPosition;
                    if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            //
                        }
                        else {
                            isLiked = false;
                            tidurPutHeart(isChecked, getAdapterPosition());
                            appPreferences.deleteCard(story.getIdStory());
                            updateLikes();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        } //setviewdata

        public void updateLikes() {
            if (!isLiked && storyList.get(changedItemPosition).getIsLiked() == 0) { //jika like dicabut (pada posisi hati yang sedang merah) di halaman favourite list
                storyList.get(changedItemPosition).setIsLiked(0); //maka cabut juga warna merah di halaman favourite list
                storyList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), storyList.size());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
            }

        } //updateLikes

    } //viewholder

    public class yukulViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private CheckBox likeCheckBox;

        public yukulViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            likeCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button_cb);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // send selected contact in callback
                    Story story = storyList.get(getLayoutPosition());
                    int ambilId = Integer.parseInt(story.getIdStory());

                    if (0 == ambilId) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaMauTidur.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else if (1 == ambilId) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaBangunt.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else if (2 == ambilId) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaJimak.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No destination page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        } //itemview

            public void viewDataYukul(final YukulModel story, final int adapterPosition) {

                textView.setText(story.getName());

                if (story.getIsLiked() == 1) {
                    likeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
                }
                else {
                    likeCheckBox.setChecked(true);
                }

                boolean isChecked = yukulGetHeart(getAdapterPosition()); // The problem lays here
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(isChecked);

                likeCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        changedItemPosition = adapterPosition;
                        if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
                            if (isChecked) {
                                //
                            }
                            else {
                                isLiked = false;
                                yukulPutHeart(isChecked, getAdapterPosition());
                                appPreferences.deleteCardYukul(story.getIdStory());
                                updateLikeYukul();
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            } //viewdatayukul

        public void updateLikeYukul() {
            if (!isLiked && yukulList.get(changedItemPosition).getIsLiked() == 0) { //jika like dicabut (pada posisi hati yang sedang merah) di halaman favourite list
                yukulList.get(changedItemPosition).setIsLiked(0); //maka cabut juga warna merah di halaman favourite list
                yukulList.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), yukulList.size());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        } //updateLikes

    } //yukulviewholder


} //HomeAdapter
```

I hope someone can fix this problem so as I can display both of them.

**CODE UPDATED [WORK]**

**AdapterFavList1.java**

```
public class AdapterFavList1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public static final String ACTION_LIKE_IMAGE_CLICKEDD = "action_like_image_button";
    final int VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR = 0;
    final int VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL = 1;

    private Context context;
    private AppPreferences appPreferences;
    private List<Story> storyList;
    private List<YukulModel> yukulList;
    private List<Object> collection = new ArrayList<Object>();

    private int changedItemPosition;
    private int posisiItemYukul;
    private boolean isLiked;

    public AdapterFavList1(Context context, List<Story> storyList, List<YukulModel> yukulList, AppPreferences appPreferences) {

        this.context = context;
        this.storyList = storyList;
        this.yukulList = yukulList;
        this.appPreferences = appPreferences;

        addData();
    }

    public void addData() {
        storyList = appPreferences.getFavouriteCardList();
        yukulList = appPreferences.getFavouriteYukul();

        if(storyList != null && storyList.size() > 0) {
            collection.addAll(storyList);
        }

        if(yukulList != null && yukulList.size() > 0) {
            collection.addAll(yukulList);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR) {
            return new tidurViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_story_favourite_list, parent, false));
        }
        if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL) {
            return new yukulViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_favourite_yukul, parent, false));
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Object item = collection.get(position);

        if(holder instanceof tidurViewHolder){
            ((tidurViewHolder) holder).setViewData((Story) item, holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }

        if(holder instanceof yukulViewHolder){
            ((yukulViewHolder) holder).viewDataYukul((YukulModel) item, holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return collection.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        Object item = collection.get(position);

        if(item instanceof Story) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR;
        }

        if(item instanceof YukulModel){
            return VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    public void tidurPutHeart(boolean isChecked, Story tidurstory) {
        SharedPreferences tidursharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Turu", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor tidureditor = tidursharedPreferences.edit();
        tidureditor.putBoolean(tidurstory.getIdStory(), isChecked);
        tidureditor.commit();
    }

    public void yukulPutHeart(boolean isChecked, YukulModel yukulstory) {
        SharedPreferences yukulsharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Yukul", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor yukuleditor = yukulsharedPreferences.edit();
        yukuleditor.putBoolean(yukulstory.getIdStory(), isChecked);
        yukuleditor.commit();
    }

    //ViewHolder
    public class tidurViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private CheckBox likeCheckBox;

        public tidurViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            likeCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button_cb);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // send selected contact in callback
                    Story story = storyList.get(getLayoutPosition());
                    int ambilId = Integer.parseInt(story.getIdStory());

                    if (0 == ambilId) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaMauTidur.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else if (1 == ambilId) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaBangunt.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else if (2 == ambilId) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaJimak.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No destination page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        } // itemView


        public void setViewData(final Story story, final int adapterPosition) {

            textView.setText(story.getName());

            if (story.getIsLiked() == 1) {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            }
            else {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            }

            likeCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    changedItemPosition = adapterPosition;

                    if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            //
                        }
                        else {
                            isLiked = false;
                            tidurPutHeart(isChecked, story);
                            appPreferences.deleteCard(story.getIdStory());
                            updateLikes();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if(collection.size() == 0) {
                                ((Activity)context).finish();
                                context.startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        } //setviewdata

        public void updateLikes() {
            if (!isLiked && storyList.get(changedItemPosition).getIsLiked() == 0) { //jika like dicabut (pada posisi hati yang sedang merah) di halaman favourite list
                storyList.get(changedItemPosition).setIsLiked(0); //maka cabut juga warna merah di halaman favourite list
                notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), collection.size());
                collection.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
            }

        } //updateLikes

    } //viewholder

    public class yukulViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private CheckBox likeCheckBox;

        public yukulViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            likeCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.like_button_cb);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // send selected contact in callback
                    Story story = storyList.get(getLayoutPosition());
                    int ambilId = Integer.parseInt(story.getIdStory());

                    if (0 == ambilId) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaMauTidur.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else if (1 == ambilId) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaBangunt.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else if (2 == ambilId) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DoaJimak.class);
                        view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No destination page", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        } //itemview

        public void viewDataYukul(final YukulModel yukulId, final int adapterPosition) {

            textView.setText(yukulId.getName());

            if (yukulId.getIsLiked() == 1) {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(false);
            }
            else {
                likeCheckBox.setChecked(true);
            }

            likeCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    posisiItemYukul = adapterPosition;

                    if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
                        if (isChecked) {
                            //
                        }
                        else {
                            isLiked = false;
                            yukulPutHeart(isChecked, yukulId);
                            appPreferences.deleteCardYukul(yukulId.getIdStory());
                            updateLikeYukul();
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            if(collection.size() == 0) {
                                ((Activity)context).finish();
                                context.startActivity(((Activity) context).getIntent());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

        } //viewdatayukul

        public void updateLikeYukul() {
            if (!isLiked && yukulList.get(changedItemPosition).getIsLiked() == 0) { //jika like dicabut (pada posisi hati yang sedang merah) di halaman favourite list
                yukulList.get(changedItemPosition).setIsLiked(0); //maka cabut juga warna merah di halaman favourite list
                notifyItemRangeChanged(getAdapterPosition(), collection.size());
                collection.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        } //updateLikes

    } //yukulviewholder


} //HomeAdapter
```

**ShowFavouriteList.java**

```
private void fetchData() {
        List<Story> storyList = appPreferences.getFavouriteCardList();
        List<YukulModel> yukulList = appPreferences.getFavouriteYukul();

        if(storyList != null && storyList.size() > 0) {
            showNoFavtText(false);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new AdapterFavList1(this, storyList, yukulList, appPreferences));
        }

        if(yukulList != null && yukulList.size() > 0) {
            showNoFavtText(false);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new AdapterFavList1(this, storyList, yukulList, appPreferences));
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would suggest is instead of using 2 lists within your adapter, just use 1 list that contains `Objects`. This will reduce a lot of the complexity, and you can just check what the actual type is when you need it.

```
public class AdapterFavList1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public static final String ACTION_LIKE_IMAGE_CLICKEDD = "action_like_image_button";

    final int VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR = 0;
    final int VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL = 1;

    private Context context;
    private int changedItemPosition;
    private boolean isLiked;
    private AppPreferences appPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    private List<Object> collection = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public AdapterFavList1(Context context, List<Story> storyList, List<YukulModel> yukulList, AppPreferences appPreferences) {
        this.context = context;
        this.appPreferences = appPreferences;

        // TODO: Sort these however you wish.
        collection.addAll(storyList);
        collection.addAll(yukulList);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR) {
            return new tidurViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_story_favourite_list, parent, false));
        }
        if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL) {
            return new yukulViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_favourite_yukul, parent, false));
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Object item = collection.get(position);

        if(holder instanceof tidurViewHolder){
            ((tidurViewHolder) holder).setViewData((Story) item, holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }

        if(holder instanceof yukulViewHolder){
            ((yukulViewHolder) holder).viewDataYukul((YukulModel) item, holder.getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return collection.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position){
        Object item = collection.get(position);

        if(item instanceof Story) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR;
        }

        if(item instanceof YukulModel){
            return VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL;
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq I removed a lot of your other code, I was only showing you what to change, not the entire working solution. You need to keep your other code in there too.

Comment: I know, it's difficult for you to write entire the code. But, could you give me an article or link that about this problem?. Maybe, it will be more helpful. Thanks

Comment: @Sa'adAbdurrazzaq I omitted the other code because it's not necessary, for example your `ViewHolders` are not changed. You can just keep those as they are, and make the changes I suggested. I don't want to supply just the entire completed code as then people won't learn from it.

Comment: Thanks mate... Your code is work after I've tried to change the rest of them. I've updated the code above!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check how you have overridden the getItemViewType() and getItemCount() methods in your adapter.

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(storyList== null) {
            return yukulList.size();
        }
        else if(storyList != null) {
            return storyList.size();
        }

        if(yukulList==null) {
            return storyList.size();
        }
        else {
            return yukulList.size();
        }

    }

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
    if(storyList != null && storyList.size() > 0){
        return VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR;
    }

    if(yukulList != null && yukulList.size() > 0){
        return VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

In your implementation of getItemViewType(), if there is any storyList data, only that data will be displayed in your recyclerView because, VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR will be returned for every position value passed to the method. The program flow will never reach the condition check for yukulList, unless storyList data is null or empty.

So in your getItemViewType() implementation, you need to determine what type of item you want to display at the position passed to the method, and accordingly return either VIEW_TYPE_TIDUR or VIEW_TYPE_YUKUL.

Also in your implementation of getItemCount(), you are returning size for only one type. You should return the combined count of storyList and yukulList sizes.

Comment: You've been thinking about what I've thought about before. 
Both of them contains data, and can be displayed in activity. But the problem is, it can't displayed in one time. Once data A is displayed, data B can't displayed and vice versa... 

It will be more helpful if you write the code. Thanks

Comment: Read the answer completely. I've answered your very question only. The code is added just to point out the mistakes. You need to understand how the two methods getItemCount() and getItemViewType() work

Comment: Yes,, and what is solution...? I've been thinking about that. I need a solution, not point out the mistakes, cause I knew that...